# What is wrong with this stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I keep getting this error for the below MySQL SP 
any ideas?

> CREATE PROCEDURE productpricing(
>   OUT pl DECIMAL(8,2),    OUT ph
>   DECIMAL(8,2),    OUT pa DECIMAL(8,2) )
>   BEGIN    SELECT Min(amount)    INTO pl
>   FROM Card Error Code: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '' at line 9 0.000 sec

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS productpricing;
CREATE PROCEDURE productpricing(
   OUT pl DECIMAL(8,2),
   OUT ph DECIMAL(8,2),
   OUT pa DECIMAL(8,2)
)
BEGIN
   SELECT Min(amount)
   INTO pl
   FROM Card;
END;
```

Comment: What are **ph** and **pa** for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you define a delimiter?

Try adding `delimiter //` before the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement. Also replace `END;` with `END;//`. I checked and it works for me.

See [the MySQL doc on stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

Answer (score 0):

you need group by if you use min,max i think. if that doesnt work try #p1 to create a temp table. May be problem is the table you are inserting it to.