# I keep getting MySQL error #1054, when trying to perform procedure

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `practica8`(e_nombre varchar(255) , e_puesto varchar(255), e_fecha_contratacion date, e_departamento varchar (255))
BEGIN
declare aux int default (select max(noEmpleado) as mx from empleado);
    insert into empleado (noEmpleado, nombre, puesto, fecha_contratacion, Comision, depto) values(
        aux + 1, e_nombre,
        (select IdPuesto from puesto where lower(Puesto) = lower(e_puesto)),
        e_fecha_contratacion, 
        (select IdDepto from departamento where lower(Nombre) = (e_departamento)));
END
```

this is the way i'm trying to run it

```
call practica8(e_nombre, e_puesto, e_fecha_contratacion, e_departamento)
```

Comment: Did you use `DELIMITER` before the procedure definition?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560791/what-is-wrong-with-this-stored-procedure?rq=1

Comment: `aux + 1` I hope this isn't the PRIMARY KEY

Comment: I'm still learning mysql, I don't know much about stored procedures

Comment: recommend not using them. no added value over an insert query

Answer (score 0):

Your call statement is incorrect, you should either pass values in your call statement or user defined variables

for example

```
call practica8(1,2,3,4)
```

or

```
set  @e_nombre = 1;
set  @e_puesto = 2;
set  @e_fecha_contratacion =3;
set  @e_departamento = 4;

call practica8(@e_nombre, @e_puesto, @e_fecha_contratacion, @e_departamento);
```

the values or UDVs will be placed in the variables defined in the create statement parameter list.