# Syntax error in MySQL procedure while using if else insert query

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I am trying to create a stored procedure with MySQL but I kept receiving the error prompt but i cant find the error in my query.

I'm coming from MS SQL background and I'm not sure how is my query wrong. Anyone understands the error?

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_AddUpdateUser
(
    IN InputUsername VARCHAR(512),
    IN InputPassword VARCHAR(512),
    IN InputEmail VARCHAR(512)
)
BEGIN

    if(NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TB_User WHERE Username = InputUsername)) then
            INSERT INTO TB_User(Username, Password, Email, DateCreated)
            SELECT InputUsername, InputPassword, InputEmail, Now();
    else
            UPDATE TB_User SET Password = InputPassword, Email = InputEmail WHERE Username = InputUsername;        
    end if;
END;;
```

Comment: mysql doesn't support NVARCHAR. Please check again. end every command with semi colon ;

Comment: Why don't you use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`?

Comment: @AmitVerma Thanks, i changed my table to use VARCHAR now and added semicolon behind command, but it is still showing error. I had updated my questions to show the latest error.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, tried with your suggestion but its still showing error.

Comment: Did you remember to change the delimiter before defining the procedure?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560791/what-is-wrong-with-this-stored-procedure?rq=1

Comment: Thanks guys, found out my issue. Turns out i've been trying to compile all create procedure inside single script but i never specify the delimiter to separate different procedure, hence the delimiter ;; is not working at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking the wrong approach in MySQL.  It has a single statement that supports "upserts" -- and `insert` with `on duplicate key update`.

This is triggered when you have a unique index or constraint on the column that cannot be duplicated.  In this case, `username`.

Start with a unique constraint or index:

```
create unique index unq_tb_user_username on TB_User(username);
```

You may already have this. Then, the body of the procedure would simply be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_AddUpdateUser
(
    IN InputUsername VARCHAR(512),
    IN InputPassword VARCHAR(512),
    IN InputEmail VARCHAR(512)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TB_User(Username, Password, Email, DateCreated)
        SELECT InputUsername, InputPassword, InputEmail, Now()
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Password = InputPassword, Email = InputEmail;
END;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b040a472ad869a19b258e4e76dadc89d) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Put **;** after now(). In stored scripts you have to use semicolon after each statement.

Comment: Thanks, but i had just edited my question. new error prompt up after i add semicolon

Comment: Try this syntax for insert 

INSERT INTO TB_User(Username, Password, Email, DateCreated) VALUES (InputUsername, InputPassword, InputEmail, Now());