Problems with MySQL stored procedure
I am trying to compile the following (see below) MySQL stored procedure and I keep getting Error Code 1064.
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3 0.000 sec"
The purpose of the procedure is to cycle through menu_input table to gather parameters for building insert queries to populate data_ouput table.
The error line seems broken as it locates the error at the beginning of the script whereas that same beginning which is related to variables declaration compiles by himself. Also, if I'm not wrong, the error suggests using server syntax; I tried reviewing each statement of my code, comparing it to official syntax but found no deviation (also due to my limited experience).
The script follows:
CREATE PROCEDURE SodAnalysis()
BEGIN
    DECLARE strFieldName1 VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE strFieldName2 VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE strSQL VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE rischio VARCHAR(100); -- Assuming these parameters need to be declared
    DECLARE categoria VARCHAR(100); -- and assigned values before executing @strSQL

    -- Cursor to iterate through menu_input records
    DECLARE menu_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT 
        menu1, 
        menu2, 
        rischio, 
        categoria
    FROM menu_input;

    OPEN menu_cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM menu_cursor INTO strFieldName1, strFieldName2, rischio, categoria; -- Adjusted to fetch @rischio and @categoria as well

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 DO
        -- Construct the SQL query with parameters A and B
        SET strSQL = CONCAT('
            INSERT INTO data_output 
            SELECT 
                c.*, 
                d.funzione AS funzione2, 
                d.processo AS processo2 
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                    a.*, 
                    b.funzione AS funzione1, 
                    b.processo AS processo1 
                FROM (
                    SELECT 
                        t1.id AS id1, 
                        t2.id AS id2, 
                        t1.utente_cod, 
                        t1.utente_des, 
                        t1.societa AS societa1, 
                        t1.societa_des AS societa_des1, 
                        t2.societa AS societa2, 
                        t2.societa_des AS societa_des2, 
                        t1.ruolo_cod AS ruolo_cod1, 
                        t1.ruolo_des AS ruolo_des1, 
                        t2.ruolo_cod AS ruolo_cod2, 
                        t2.ruolo_des AS ruolo_des2, 
                        t1.modulo AS modulo1, 
                        t2.modulo AS modulo2, 
                        t1.modulo_des AS modulo_des1, 
                        t2.modulo_des AS modulo_des2, 
                        t1.menu_funz AS menu_funz1, 
                        t2.menu_funz AS menu_funz2, 
                        t1.progr_cod AS progr_cod1, 
                        t2.progr_cod AS progr_cod2, 
                        @rischio AS rischio, 
                        @categoria AS categoria 
                    FROM 
                        data_input t1
                    INNER JOIN 
                        data_input t2 
                    ON 
                        t1.utente_cod = t2.utente_cod 
                    WHERE 
                        t1.utente_cod IN (
                            SELECT utente_cod 
                            FROM data_input 
                            WHERE menu_funz = @strFieldName1
                        ) 
                        AND t1.utente_cod IN (
                            SELECT utente_cod 
                            FROM data_input 
                            WHERE menu_funz = @strFieldName2
                        ) 
                        AND t1.menu_funz = @strFieldName1 
                        AND t2.menu_funz = @strFieldName2
                ) a 
                LEFT JOIN 
                    transcodifica_input b 
                ON 
                    a.menu_funz1 = b.MENU
            ) c 
            LEFT JOIN 
                transcodifica_input d 
            ON 
                c.menu_funz2 = d.MENU;
        ');

        -- Execute the constructed SQL query
        PREPARE stmt from StrSQL;
        SET @rischio = rischio;
        SET @categoria = categoria;
        SET @strFieldName1 = strFieldName1;
        SET @strFieldName2 = strFieldName2;
        EXECUTE stmt USING @rischio, @categoria, @strFieldName1, @strFieldName2;
        deallocate prepare stmt;

        -- Move to the next record
        FETCH NEXT FROM menu_cursor INTO strFieldName1, strFieldName2, rischio, categoria; -- Adjusted to fetch @rischio and @categoria as well
    END WHILE;

    -- Close and deallocate the cursor
    CLOSE menu_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE menu_cursor;
END;
GO

I wish you the best hoping anyone could give a hand, Best Regards, David
I am executing the code in MySQL Workbench configured with 'Dedicated' setting during install. My target database product is MySQL. I am doing everything in MySQL environment, I haven't heard of ms sql server so far. UPDATED Thank y'all for your vital support - I have made some pseudo-progess (v2) with the code for the procedure creation currently compiling, but when I try to run the procedure I get error:
Additional Info: menu1 and menu2 are text columns of the following table used to create an insert statement for each row of menu_input table

CREATE TABLE `menu_input` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `menu1` text,
  `menu2` text,
  `rischio` text,
  `categoria` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=63 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
;


17:44:38    call SodAnalysis()  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1    0.000 sec
Code:
-- Change the delimiter to $$ to avoid conflicts with semicolons in the procedure
DELIMITER $$

-- Create a new stored procedure named SodAnalysis
CREATE PROCEDURE SodAnalysis()

BEGIN

    -- Declare a variable to indicate when the cursor has finished reading all rows
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

    -- Declare variables to hold values from the menu_input table
    DECLARE menu1 VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE menu2 VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE rischio VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE categoria VARCHAR(255);

    -- Declare a variable to hold the dynamic SQL string
    DECLARE str VARCHAR(255);

    -- Define a cursor to iterate over the rows in the menu_input table
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT 
        menu1, 
        menu2, 
        rischio, 
        categoria
    FROM menu_input;

    -- Declare a handler to set the done variable to TRUE when the cursor reaches the end of the result set
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    -- Open the cursor
    OPEN cur;

    -- Start a loop to read each row from the cursor
    read_loop: LOOP

        -- Fetch the next row into the variables
        FETCH cur INTO menu1, menu2, rischio, categoria;

        -- If no more rows are left, exit the loop
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        -- Set variables for dynamic SQL
        SET @a = menu1;
        SET @b = menu2;
        SET @c = rischio;
        SET @d = categoria;

        -- Construct the dynamic SQL query string
        SET @str = CONCAT('
            INSERT INTO data_output 
            SELECT 
                c.*, 
                d.funzione AS funzione2, 
                d.processo AS processo2 
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                    a.*, 
                    b.funzione AS funzione1, 
                    b.processo AS processo1 
                FROM (
                    SELECT 
                        t1.id AS id1, 
                        t2.id AS id2, 
                        t1.utente_cod, 
                        t1.utente_des, 
                        t1.societa AS societa1, 
                        t1.societa_des AS societa_des1, 
                        t2.societa AS societa2, 
                        t2.societa_des AS societa_des2, 
                        t1.ruolo_cod AS ruolo_cod1, 
                        t1.ruolo_des AS ruolo_des1, 
                        t2.ruolo_cod AS ruolo_cod2, 
                        t2.ruolo_des AS ruolo_des2, 
                        t1.modulo AS modulo1, 
                        t2.modulo AS modulo2, 
                        t1.modulo_des AS modulo_des1, 
                        t2.modulo_des AS modulo_des2, 
                        t1.menu_funz AS menu_funz1, 
                        t2.menu_funz AS menu_funz2, 
                        t1.progr_cod AS progr_cod1, 
                        t2.progr_cod AS progr_cod2, 
                        ', @c,' AS rischio, 
                        ', @d,' AS categoria 
                    FROM 
                        data_input t1
                    INNER JOIN 
                        data_input t2 
                    ON 
                        t1.utente_cod = t2.utente_cod 
                    WHERE 
                        t1.utente_cod IN (
                            SELECT utente_cod 
                            FROM data_input 
                            WHERE menu_funz = ', @a,'
                        ) 
                        AND t1.utente_cod IN (
                            SELECT utente_cod 
                            FROM data_input 
                            WHERE menu_funz = ', @b,'
                        ) 
                        AND t1.menu_funz = ', @a,' 
                        AND t2.menu_funz = ', @b,'
                ) a 
                LEFT JOIN 
                    transcodifica_input b 
                ON 
                    a.menu_funz1 = b.MENU
            ) c 
            LEFT JOIN 
                transcodifica_input d 
            ON 
                c.menu_funz2 = d.MENU;
        ');

        -- Prepare and execute the dynamic SQL statement
        PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
        EXECUTE stmt using @a, @b, @c, @d;

        -- Deallocate the prepared statement
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    END LOOP;

    -- Close the cursor
    CLOSE cur;

END $$

-- Restore the delimiter to semicolon
DELIMITER ;


GO?? @@fetch_status? Are you attempting to run sql server code in mysql or have you tagged incorrectly??

I am trying to create a stored procedure on locally hosted MySQL database, also I'm a newbie so I don't really get the difference between SQL Server code and SQL Client code

mysql and sql server are very different, if you are learning sql server install a version of sql server if not you need to work through some mysql tutorials.

@P.Salmon GO does work in mysql's command line client, but @@fetch_status is truly not supported in mysql in any way.

@user25436251 please let us know what is your target database product (mysql or ms sql server) and in what client you try to execute the code in the question.

Will update post

Where did you learn to use WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0? It seems like you must have copied that from a SQL-Server tutorial rather than MySQL, because it's not valid here.

However, I don't think it has anything to do with the error message you got. I believe that's because you didn't use DELIMITER to change change the query delimiter away from ;, so you can use it as the statement delimiter in the procedure. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560791/what-is-wrong-with-this-stored-procedure?rq=1

Updated the post, not using @@fetch_status anymore, thank you all for the support

The other comments are not clearly stating this, but they are talking about Microsoft SQL Server, which is a different software product from MySQL. They are made by different companies, and they have many different features and syntax. It's like you're using an iPhone but you're reading documentation for Android.

What full error message do you get for the later version of your code?  What is on line 122?  What's stored in menu1 or menu2, column names or strinhs?

You cannot use declared variables in a prepare statement but you can use user defined variables as the error message hints and the manual states ' preparable_stmt is either a string literal or a user variable t' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/prepare.html see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql

Thanks everyone, I am doing my best to update the code based on your suggestions. I have updated the post including new code with the latest compiling error plus the additional info requested. Right now, the biggest problem I have besides being inexperienced and getting this procedure to fullfil its purpose is debugging the code. Because the creation of the procedure compiles but it doesn't run, and the error is no longer placed at its real souce-line I guess.

Thanks everyone who helped me in achieving this little for some but big for me result, the script now works and I will leave it here for any internet traveller who might be experiencing or will experience the same problems I faced. The internet really does sometimes reach humanity's highest point towards a sharing, caring and loving world. Let's free knowledge, let us free humanity traveller, or at least let's try ;) truly yours -David
-- Change the delimiter to $$ to avoid conflicts with semicolons in the procedure
DELIMITER $$

-- Create a new stored procedure named SodAnalysis
CREATE PROCEDURE SodAnalysis()

BEGIN

    -- Declare a variable to indicate when the cursor has finished reading all rows
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

    -- Declare variables to hold values from the menu_input table
    DECLARE sto_menu1 TEXT;
    DECLARE sto_menu2 TEXT;
    DECLARE sto_rischio TEXT;
    DECLARE sto_categoria TEXT;

    -- Declare a variable to hold the dynamic SQL string
    DECLARE str VARCHAR(255);

    -- Define a cursor to iterate over the rows in the menu_input table
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT 
        sodanalysis.menu_input.menu1, 
        sodanalysis.menu_input.menu2, 
        sodanalysis.menu_input.rischio, 
        sodanalysis.menu_input.categoria
    FROM sodanalysis.menu_input;

    -- Declare a handler to set the done variable to TRUE when the cursor reaches the end of the result set
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    -- Open the cursor
    OPEN cur;

    -- Start a loop to read each row from the cursor
    read_loop: LOOP

        -- Fetch the next row into the variables
        FETCH cur INTO sto_menu1, sto_menu2, sto_rischio, sto_categoria;

        -- If no more rows are left, exit the loop
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        -- Set variables for dynamic SQL
        SET @a = sto_menu1;
        SET @b = sto_menu2;
        SET @c = sto_rischio;
        SET @d = sto_categoria;
        
               -- Construct the dynamic SQL query string
        SET @str = CONCAT('
            INSERT INTO data_output 
            SELECT 
                c.*, 
                d.funzione AS funzione2, 
                d.processo AS processo2 
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                    a.*, 
                    b.funzione AS funzione1, 
                    b.processo AS processo1 
                FROM (
                    SELECT 
                        t1.id AS id1, 
                        t2.id AS id2, 
                        t1.utente_cod, 
                        t1.utente_des, 
                        t1.societa AS societa1, 
                        t1.societa_des AS societa_des1, 
                        t2.societa AS societa2, 
                        t2.societa_des AS societa_des2, 
                        t1.ruolo_cod AS ruolo_cod1, 
                        t1.ruolo_des AS ruolo_des1, 
                        t2.ruolo_cod AS ruolo_cod2, 
                        t2.ruolo_des AS ruolo_des2, 
                        t1.modulo AS modulo1, 
                        t2.modulo AS modulo2, 
                        t1.modulo_des AS modulo_des1, 
                        t2.modulo_des AS modulo_des2, 
                        t1.menu_funz AS menu_funz1, 
                        t2.menu_funz AS menu_funz2, 
                        t1.progr_cod AS progr_cod1, 
                        t2.progr_cod AS progr_cod2, 
                        ''', @c,''' AS rischio, 
                        ''', @d,''' AS categoria 
                    FROM 
                        data_input t1
                    INNER JOIN 
                        data_input t2 
                    ON 
                        t1.utente_cod = t2.utente_cod 
                    WHERE 
                        t1.utente_cod IN (
                            SELECT utente_cod 
                            FROM data_input 
                            WHERE menu_funz = ''', @a,'''
                        ) 
                        AND t1.utente_cod IN (
                            SELECT utente_cod 
                            FROM data_input 
                            WHERE menu_funz = ''', @b,'''
                        ) 
                        AND t1.menu_funz = ''', @a,''' 
                        AND t2.menu_funz = ''', @b,'''
                ) a 
                LEFT JOIN 
                    transcodifica_input b 
                ON 
                    a.menu_funz1 = b.MENU
            ) c 
            LEFT JOIN 
                transcodifica_input d 
            ON 
                c.menu_funz2 = d.MENU;
        ');
        
        select @str from dual;

        
        -- Prepare and execute the dynamic SQL statement
        PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
        EXECUTE stmt;

        -- Deallocate the prepared statement
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
        

    END LOOP;

    -- Close the cursor
    CLOSE cur;
END $$

-- Restore the delimiter to semicolon
DELIMITER ;

